# Entity Framework | GroupBy and Sum

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

I have a simple table which only has 3 columns `{ id, DateTime, NumberOfCoils }`, I need to get the results of the query grouped together by the `DateTime` with the sum of the `NumberOfCoils` on that particular date.

```
return testData.MOCK_DATA.Select(x => new { x.NumberOfCoils, x.DateTime })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => x.DateTime> DateTime.Now.AddDays(-numberOfDays))
            .Select(x => new { formattedDate = x.DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), x.NumberOfCoils })
            .OrderBy(x => x.formattedDate)
            .ToList();
```

I've looked for solutions here but I couldn't figure out how to solve it. I think that part of what's making it hard for me to find a solution is because I have to do some formatting as well.

I'm pretty new to using EF so I apologize if this is a bad question.

Comment: You should do the where before the `AsEnumerable` to send it to the database engine, unless you want to pull the entire table into memory before filtering for some reason. In fact you should only do `AsEnumerable` if you can't do without it in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return testData.MOCK_DATA.Select(x => new { x.NumberOfCoils, x.DateTime })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => x.DateTime> DateTime.Now.AddDays(-numberOfDays))
            .GroupBy(x => x.DateTime)
            .Sum(x => x.NumberOfCoils);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, .Sum(x => x.NumberOfCoils) can't find a definition or extension method for NumberOfCoils.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually use `GroupBy`:

```
return testData.MOCK_DATA.Where(x => x.DateTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-numberOfDays))
                         .GroupBy(d => d.DateTime)
                         .Select(dg => new { formattedDate = dg.Key.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), NumberOfCoils = dg.Sum(d => d.NumberOfCoils) })
                         .OrderBy(x => x.formattedDate)
                         .ToList();
```